# Static code Analysis

Tags: c

Are there some possibility to complete a static code Analysis of C code with a minGW? I have read, that there is a possibility to do it with the help of mygcc. But is it possible to do it with *MinGW*?

Comment: by the way there is an official port of `llvm` and `clang` for Windows; not really 100% up-to-date like the main branch, but it's interesting enough to deserve a try.

Comment: I have edited your question hoping to make it clearer what you are asking, but please check for if it still matches you original intent. I am still not 100% sure what you want, but recommendations for tools are generally off-topic here.

Comment: I am not sure this is technically asking for a recommendation, it is asking if a particular tool can be used for a specific purpose. The answers might be to use something else, but I think the question is valid

Answer (score 1):

Mingw (or, generally, gcc toolchain) don't have designated static analysis tool. Clang have one (`clang --analyze`). Other options are `cppcheck` or whole lot of non-free analysers (like coverity or PVS-studio).

Comment: cppcheck is for cpp though?

Comment: @mjs no, it works with C99/C11 just as well. I use it to periodically scan codebase (along with clang analyser, too).

Answer (score 0):

This question will probably get flagged as off topic, but i think it is valid so...

Your first step is to ensure that all warnings are turned on, ( and i prefer to make warnings errors, because very, very, very rarely is a warning not an actual bug waiting to smack you in the face). In gcc (which i believe MingW uses), you would do this with `-Wall -Werror`. You might even turn on `-Wextra` for yet-more-warnings - although even this still doesn't turn on everything, and you may want to enable specific warnings such as  `-Winit-self` - but fix the low hanging fruit first.

Do this, and fix everything first, before moving to a separate static analysis tool.

There are many, many static analysis tools available for the c language. Typically, you would modify your build system to run the analysis tool either directly before or after your compiler as part of your build process, so that all warnings and errors appear in a single place.

Examples include Lint, QAC (commercial but powerful). I did hear that there was some work to get CLang working with  MingW - maybe that is what you are refering to?.

Which static analysis tool is best for you will depend on your project requirements, and budget. For instance, do you need to certify against particular standards (eg MISRA, or specific defence standards etc)?

You should also use `valgrind` as a matter of course. This is a dynamic analysis tool, but very, very useful.

Comment: Unfortunately even `-Wextra` don't include `-Winit-self`. Some of my favorite bugs comes from this one, recommending to include it too.

Comment: Good point. updated answer to indicate that other options may need to be specifically enabled